# Eclipse Indigo with JDK9

Tags: eclipse, java, java-9

I wanted to try the newest Java from the [openJdk9 repository](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9) with my rather ancient Eclipse. I downloaded, build, and installed it, everything worked fine. Then I set it up as the default JVM for Eclipse, everything got recompiled, but with errors since base Java classes like `java.lang.CharSequence` don't get found.

The build path looks fine and so does `rt.jar`.
[image: build path]

Is there something blocking Eclipse Indigo from using JDK9? I'm not trying to investigater the new Java features, just wanted to measure the performance using the most recent version.

Comment: uh that's not the newest Java, the newest Java is going to be Java 8 when it gets a final release in March. This must be a pre-pre-pre checkin of the next development cycle.

Comment: I believe the IDE may be making some assumptions about the JRE it is using. These assumptions fail (obviously) for a JRE which is yet to enter the alpha phase. Another concern: Eclipse uses its own compiler, that's bound to cause trouble.

Comment: does your drive contains rt.jar? That should dissapear on Java 9 and could perhaps make a serious mess.

Answer (score 0):

The message is clear from the Eclipse maintainers **::**

> [Indigo](https://projects.eclipse.org/releases/indigo) is a past version of Eclipse. Please visit our download page
>   for the latest version of Eclipse.

You shall upgrade to using ***[Eclipse Oxygen.1a (4.7.1a) Release](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/)*** released on October 11, 2017 to support JPMS.

---

On the other side of it

> The build path looks fine and so does rt.jar.

Java 9 involved the process of [Removing rt.jar and tools.jar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/migrate/toc.htm#JSMIG-GUID-D867DCCC-CEB5-4AFA-9D11-9C62B7A3FAB1) to aim to restructure images as *[Modular Run-Time Images](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/9-relnote-issues-3704069.html#JDK-8049367)*. Henceforth **:-**

> Tools and libraries that rely on the existence of the jre directory,
>   ***rt.jar***, or ***tools.jar*** may need to be updated to work with the new
>   layout and/or may need to be updated to use the ***jrt*** file system
>   provider to access class files and other resources in the runtime
>   image.